# Яндекс.Карты Api: При событии выдает ошибку

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, события

При включенном дебаге выдает ошибку:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: listener.call is not a function
```

в данной строке(19124 строка)

```
listener.call(listeners[j + 1], eventObject);
```

Код автоматически генерируется в php:

```
 ymaps.ready(function() { 
    $Maps['yandex_map'] = new ymaps.Map('yandex_map', 
    {
        "center":[43.234431,76.923708]
    }, {}); 
    $Maps['yandex_map'].events.add("click", "function (e) {
      alert(\"О, событие!\");
    }");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут вы в callback передаете строку:

```
$Maps['yandex_map'].events.add("click", "function (e) {
      alert(\"О, событие!\");
    }");
```

А надо функцию (обратите внимание на отсутствие кавычек):

```
$Maps['yandex_map'].events.add("click", function (e) {
      alert(\"О, событие!\");
    });
```

Comment: Не заметил сразу. Вы мне сэкономили минимум час поисков. Спасибо